# If query result is null it didnt execute next statements in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

```
$user = User:: select('name', 'email_id', 'gender')
              ->where($field, "=", $postData['login'])
                ->where("password", "=", sha1($postData['password']))
                ->first();

        if ($user) {
            $token=str_random(60);
            $user->api_token=$token;
            $user->save();

            $response['status'] = 200;
            $response['message'] = "success";
            $response['data'] = $user;
        }
        else {
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $response['message'] = "failure";
        }
```

In this code, the "if" statements only run if $user has some value, which is obvious but if $user is null, next statements didnt execute.

Even if i write echo "anything" just below query, it didnt display it, it just return null. So i didnt get values written in else block.

I have tried different things, but fails in that.

Comment: So the `else` is not executed when the user is null. Have you tried an dd instead of an echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no user with the given criteria, the query might be throwing "ModelNotFoundException", Can you try catching the exception and see if that is the case?

```
try {
$user = User:: select('name', 'email_id', 'gender')
          ->where($field, "=", $postData['login'])
            ->where("password", "=", sha1($postData['password']))
            ->first();
} catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException e) {
    dd(e);
}
```